# How to build FileInputStream object with byte array as a parameter

Tags: java, performance, jakarta-ee, arrays, fileinputstream

I have a zip file and after decoding it I get a byte array now I want to create a FileInputStream object with that byte[] object. I dont want to create a file instead pass data content do FileInputStream.
Is there any way ?

following is the code:

```
byte[] decodedHeaderFileZip = decodeHeaderZipFile(headerExportFile);
FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(decodedHeaderZipFileString);
```

EDIT:
I wanted to build a ZipInputStream object with a FileInputStream.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

> I have a zip file and after decoding it I get a byte array now I want to create a FileInputStream object with that byte[] object.

But you don't have a file. You have some data in memory. So a `FileInputStream` is inappropriate - there's no file for it to read from.

If possible, use a `ByteArrayInputStream` instead:

```
InputStream input = new ByteArrayInputStream(decodedHeaderFileZip);
```

Where possible, express your API in terms of `InputStream`, `Reader` etc rather than any specific implementation - that allows you to be flexible in which implementation you use. (What I mean is that where possible, make method parameters and return types `InputStream` rather than `FileInputStream` - so that callers don't need to provide the specific types.)

If you absolutely *have* to create a `FileInputStream`, you'll need to write the data to a file first.

Comment: thanks..but can you please explain "express your API in terms of InputStream, Reader etc rather than any specific implementation - that allows you to be flexible in which implementation you use."

Comment: as mentioned in EDIT..with @Jon Skeets help I formed InputStream object and passed it to the ZipInputStream as a parameter and IT WORKED !! thank you :-)

Comment: @Rauf: I've edited my answer to explain what I mean about APIs. It's not clear whether you *did* have an API which needed `FileInputStream` at all, but it's still something to consider.